# ftruncate not working on POSIX shared memory in Mac OS X

Tags: c, linux, macos, shared-memory

I have written a code on Mac OS X to use POSIX shared memory as shown below:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
    int fileHandle = shm_open("TW_ShMem1",O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0666);

    if(fileHandle==-1) {
       //error.

    } else {
        //Here, it is failing on Mac OS X
        if(-1==ftruncate(fileHandle, 8192)) {
            shm_unlink("TW_ShMem1");
            fileHandle = -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

`ftruncate` on Linux is working without any problem. On Mac OS X, it is returning -1 and `errno` is `EINVAL` (as seen in the debugger).

Why is it failing? What is being missed here?

Comment: The OS X man page for ftruncate claims it can fail with `EINVAL` only if it's a socket rather than a file, it's not open for writing, or the length argument is less than zero. So, what's the value of `p_size`? And does the same thing happen if you open & ftruncate a regular file, and then `mmap` it?

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained compilable example?

Comment: memoryName is "TW9_Shm1" and size is 8192.

Comment: It works on Linux but not on Mac OS X. It failed at ftruncate.

Comment: @Useless: Yes. It is same thing. Open and ftruncate shared memory file and `mmap` it. `mmap` is done in the next function.

Comment: That still isn't a self-contained compilable example, [this](http://sscce.org/) is. You can edit the code into your question.

Comment: @Useless: See the edit. It  must help. It must compile without any problem on Mac OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like OSX behaviour - ftruncate only works once on the initial *creation* of the segment. Any subsequent calls fail in this manner. The [earliest reference](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2004/Dec/msg00066.html) I can find to this is a post to the apple mailing list.

If I put an `shm_unlink` before the `shm_open` the ftruncate works consistently.

assuming that you only want to resize the shared memory segment the once, you could wrap the ftruncate in an `fstat` to determine the current size and resize it in the case that `st_size == 0`

e.g.

```
struct stat mapstat;
if (-1 != fstat(fileHandle, &mapstat) && mapstat.st_size == 0) {
    ftruncate(fileHandle, 8192);
}
```

Comment: Note that this may introduce a race if this code runs in different threads or processes.

Comment: The OSX kernel code for shared memory regions says: [It can only be done once per shared memory region](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/a1babec6b135d1f35b2590a1990af3c5c5393479/bsd/kern/posix_shm.c#L525). The only race would be if you chose different sizes. You're still left with the same limitation - one truncate per lifetime.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `fstat` check could raise in different processes. Of course, if one just ignores the `ftruncate` return value it still works, but the `fstat` check isn't strictly speaking necessary then.