# How to use shm_open with mmap properly

Tags: c, macos, shared-memory, mmap

I am trying to create a shared memory area using examples and documentation I found online. My goal is IPC , so I can make different processes talk to each other.

This my C file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

struct stat sb;
off_t len;
char *p;
int fd;

fd = shm_open("test",  O_RDWR | O_CREAT); //,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

if (fd == -1) {
    perror("open");
    return 1;
}

if (fstat(fd, &sb)==-1){
    perror("fstat");
    return 1;
}

/*if (!S_ISREG(sb.st_mode)){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s is not a file\n",fileName);
    return 1;
}*/

p = mmap(0, sb.st_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if (p == MAP_FAILED){
    perror("mmap");


    return 1;

}

if (close(fd)==-1) {
    perror("close");
    return 1;

}
for (len = 0; len < sb.st_size; len++) {
    putchar(p[len]);

}

if (munmap(p, sb.st_size) == -1) {
    perror("munmao");
    return 1;
}
fprintf(stderr,"\n");
return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I am getting a mmap: Invalid argument. I assume something is wrong with fd but have no clue how to fix it, any help would be appreciated. I am on Yosemite using latest XCODE .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to extend the size of the shared memory mapping, at least the first time when you create it. Right now its size is 0, and mmap is not going to allow you to make a zero length mapping.

So instead of your fstat() call, do e.g.:

```
size_t len = 4096;
if (ftruncate(fd, len) == -1) {
    perror("ftruncate");
    return 1;
}
```

And pass this `len` to mmap().

Comment: I am afraid your code does not work, it gives me "ftruncate: Invalid argument"

Comment: Ok, it works fine on linux, it seems OSX has some weird behavior regarding shm_open/ftruncate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502229/ftruncate-not-working-on-posix-shared-memory-in-mac-os-x (i.e. you've ran your program several times now, so you'll need to remove the segment first. Also, your shm_open call needs a 3. argument that you commented away, hm_open("test",  O_RDWR | O_CREAT,S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR););

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have commented those segments away just for testing purposes I have tried even with them included. I think I will stick to using just open and refrain from using shm_open because I decided that I would like to store my shared memory to a file too as a backup with msync.

Answer (score -4):

Your `addr` parameter is set to `0`, which might be reserved. Did you mean to use `NULL`? This would be different than `0`.

Comment: Downvote also from me because you need to take a look at how mmap work, before providing an answer. 0 is the most used adress for mmap and if the adress is occupied the kernel will find a free adress.

Comment: [`NULL` *is* `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7016898/364696); they'd behave the same here.