# What happens when two or more threads or processes ftruncate(2) the same file?

Tags: c, file, posix, race-condition, libc

As far as I understand, `ftruncate(2)` can't be atomic when I am expanding a file upto 2 GB length.

But what exactly happens behind the scenes? I have applied it and it seems to work fine when more than one thread expands the file but I can't be sure if it doesn't cause any data loss.

Also, let's suppose 2 threads call `ftruncate(2)` at the same time, the first one is on the way to expand file to 2 GB. Meanwhile the second thread calls `ftruncate(2)`. Now the doubt is the first thread didn't finish the complete job and 2nd thread also started ftruncate, so what will happen?

Also if this causes any trouble, is using file locks a wise solution? This code I am writing is a library, so when the library is being used, I won't know state and config of the process the library is being used in. Is there a possibility of a deadlock in such a case?

Comment: Why do you suspect that the call to `ftruncate()` is non-atomic? I would presume, that it indeed is.

Comment: What system are you using? On macOS, `ftruncate` might behave a bit differently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502229/ftruncate-not-working-on-posix-shared-memory-in-mac-os-x/25510361

Comment: @BearAqua This q/a only refers to ftruncate on posix shared memory segments, not on regular files.

Comment: @Ctx But it does suggest the fact that some `ftruncate` behaviors are system-dependent.

Comment: @Ctx thanks for the info. I was thinking that because I am truncating it to 2GB length, so maybe it would not be atomic.

Comment: @BearAqua, yes I use macOS. I agree to the fact that I had some really undefined segmentation faults except of checking the code many times which led me to conclusion that somethings wrong happening after ftruncate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well answering this old question of mine, `ftruncate(2)` is atomic as far as what I observed in the past.

In the comments @BearAqua shared a link of improper functioning of `ftruncate(2)` with `POSIX shared memory` on macOS, but that's not valid for regular files.

Although as far as I remember I couldn't find it documented anywhere that `ftruncate(2)` is atomic or some similar reason, but yea as far as what I tested it is atomic.