# ftruncate return invalid argument when called twice on OSX on shared memory

Tags: c, macos, posix

This code seems to run fine on linux but fail on OSX Ventura 13.3.1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h> 

int main()
{
    int memory_object_size = 72;
    const char* m_shm_name = "/original_mutexx";
    shm_unlink(m_shm_name);
    int firstfd = shm_open(m_shm_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU); // > 0
        
    int res = ftruncate(firstfd, memory_object_size );
    if(res != 0)
    {
        printf("first object size :%d\n", k_shared_memory_object_size);
        printf("first ftruncate error :%s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    
    // does nothing
    // close(firstfd);
    // works if
    // shm_unlink(firstfd);

    int secondfd = shm_open(m_shm_name, O_RDWR, S_IRWXU); // > 0
    res = ftruncate(secondfd, memory_object_size);
    if(res != 0)
    {
        printf("second object size: %d\n", k_shared_memory_object_size);
        printf("second ftruncate error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    return 1;
}
```

return

```
second object size: 72
second ftruncate error: Invalid argument
```

Is it expected, I tried increasing the file the second time without success.

Comment: Why don't you check `firstfd` and `secondfd` values?

Comment: Check the return values for error condition.  If they indicate an error condition, check `errno` for what particular error occurred.

Comment: @Eljay the only function that fails here is the second `ftruncate` is sets errno to 22 which means (according to Mac OS X developer manual) one of the following: `fildes references a socket, not a file.` or `fildes is not open for writing.` or `The length argument is less than 0.`. None of that is relevant, looks like an OS bug to me.

Comment: @NateEldredge it is reproducible, you just need to run on Mac

Comment: ```firstfd```  and ```secondfd``` are fine

Comment: This appears to be known, longtime (mis)behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25510361/2402272.  MacOS `ftruncate()` works on a given shared-memory object only once.

Comment: Are you really using Yosemite?  You should be on a more recent version of macOS.  I've removed the [tag:osx-yosemite] tag — it isn't version-specific.  Your question title mentions macOS Ventura — I feel doubly justified in removed the Yosemite tag.